# How to return back to lockscreen after launch app when receive notification?

Tags: android, voip, lockscreen

I'm working on a VOIP app, I want to improve the user experience for my application.

**Functionally expected:**
When the device is locked (app still running), When receiving a notification for an incoming call I want my app to wake up and show incoming call screen, after ending this call the device should be locked again. The same behavior with Whatsapp, Skype, ...

**At present:**
I can wake up my app and show incoming call screen by using start an `Intent` with `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT`. Still, I cannot redirect to lock screen after ending the call.

Is there any way to go back to lock screen after end call?